# How to populate filter options with another field values?

Tags: entities, views

Consider the following nodes:
- 'Match' which has a 'field_season' field referencing to 'season' node
- 'Player' which has a 'field_seasonS' field referencing to 'season' node, allowing multiple values.

On the player's node page I created a view showing his results, with an exposed filter to 'field_season' that let me to filter out the 'Match' nodes.

I'd like to populate the exposed filter options with the values inside 'field_seasonS' of that player, letting me to choose only the seasons that player played